# Flutter archive uploading in xcode is not available in the builds in AppConnect Store

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter-ios

I am a flutter developer, I have been following up the tutorials to upload the archive to the testflight, I am using xcode to upload the distribute, The Certificates and Profile are managed by Xcode. Also I created an app in appConnectStore with the same bundle identifier. Once the uploading is done in xcode, The builds are always empty. I tried giving it some time to see if it updates late, But AppConnect store doesn't show me the build i have uploaded. I can't find any reasons why the appConnect store is not listing the builds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, They have been sending mails to the account owner, about the issue.

Comment: So, it was a bug?

Comment: @Lies, The problem was that the owner of the developer account wasn't aware of the mails received, even when i asked him. So I have created myself an appstore account and added myself to the project. Now I am getting the mails about why my app is being rejected. so It wasn't a bug, It's a human error. Although appstore could have listed the build and mark it as rejcted, so that i would have known something is wrong.